# VBA-Excel return the latest date

Tags: vba, excel

I am a newbie to using VBA to program functions in Excel (just started this morning actually). Here is my problem including my almost but non-working solution.

**Problem outline:**

I have 2 columns of data, a userID and a Date column. I want to create a function that returns the maximum date (latest) for a userID. A userID may appear once, or many times (number varies from user to user, but doesn't exceed 20).

Now to make this problem a easier for my little brain, I pre-sort the userIDs to appear one after another, and then created a third column to mark the first instance of a userID (not necessarily the one with the earliest/latest date) using a simple excel If statement: If its the first instance it is the userID, else it is empty.

Then I created a function that takes in a range of cells (userIDs), and a single other value (the third column cell containing a single value of userID)

```
A typical excel worksheet will look like this:
userID   Date     First Instance
    1    3/3/12   1
    1    3/2/11   
    1    2/3/14
    2              2
    2    3/4/15  
    2
    2    5/6/15
    3    5/5/16    3
    4    4/4/14    4
    4 
    4    6/7/08
    ...
```

I wrote the function below, which takes in userID as the iRange (I select more than 20 so that for other users which may have 20 instances of userID are also included), and idCell as the single identifier of the first instance of userId.

The logic behind the code is:

- Loop through iRange and compare it to idCell
- If it's equal, check that the next cell (next to the element from iRange is a date) and if it is
- Check whether it is larger than the maxDate, store it if true
- At the end I return maxDate

**The result:**

I get a number back, but it isn't a date and I don't think it has any bearing on a date.

```
Function returnDate2(iRange As Range, idCell As Range) As Date
    Dim elem As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    Dim maxDate As Date
    For Each elem In iRange
        If elem = idCell Then
            If IsDate(elem.Offset(0, 1)) Then
                If elem.Offset(0, 1) > maxDate Then
                    maxDate = DateValue(elem.Offset(0, 1))
                End If
                returnDate2 = maxDate
            End If
        End If
    Next elem
End Function
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's wrong with `=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$12=1,$B$2:$B$12))` entered as an array formula with Ctrl-Shift-Enter? Where `1` is the id to find, it can be changed to reference of a cell with the value seeking.

Comment: Or this `=AGGREGATE(14,6,$B$2:$B$12/($A$2:$A$12=1),1)` entered as a regular formula?

Comment: As to why you get a number, Excel store dates as numbers based on Jan 1 1900.  So we are somewhere in the 42000s now.  Simply change the number format on the output cell to a date and viola you will see a date.

Comment: Formula suggested by @ScottCraner is much better but if you still want to go with your function makes two changes: **(1)** `Function returnDate2(iRange As Range, idCell As Range) As String`  **(2)** `returnDate2 = Format(maxDate, "mm/dd/yyyy")`

Comment: You can change number to date in sheet also using `=TEXT(D2,"mm-dd-yyyy")`

Comment: @Mrig the problem with returning a string is that it no longer can be used in maths or other formulas that need to refer to it as a number.  It is better to simply change the number format of the cell itself.  Then Excel maintains the number but it looks like a date.

Comment: @ScottCraner - That's correct. So its up to OP how he wants date to be used.

Comment: @Mrig I agree I just wanted to make sure the OP knew what each choice entails.  If this is the end and it is just for output your method is nice in that it does not require a second step to get the correct format.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Programmatically or even in sheet itself, using date as number is always better than using date as string.

Comment: Thanks for all, especially @ScottCraner, for the awesome suggestions! Just changing the format of the cell did the trick. Why I used VBA instead of regular Excel formula? I didn't know about array formula *blushes*, but in hindsight, I'm glad I tried programming in VBA. Was 4 hours well spent.

Comment: @Nick Learning new things is never a waste of time, too bad our bosses can't see that.